# Android DeadObjectException Ble

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am getting

> android.os.DeadObjectException

when try to call the method `BluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification`.

My device is a Nexsus 4 with Android Lollipop 5.1.

I tried to handle the exception using this link:

[How to solve the BluetoothGatt : android.os.DeadObjectException error happened in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947874/how-to-solve-the-bluetoothgatt-android-os-deadobjectexception-error-happened-i)

but I am not able to print the stacktrace.

Comment: If your question is about printing the stack trace, see: [Java / Android - How to print out a full stack trace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841232/java-android-how-to-print-out-a-full-stack-trace).

Comment: Thnx @mins that is the secondary concern . My main concern is how to solve this issue.

Comment: In that case, please show (in your post) what you have tried, so that users here can help you to fix it. See [ask].